# In Django, how do I enable users to join a group if the user knows the group password?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

In Django I'd like to allow logged-in users to join a group if they enter the right PIN/password. Users should not be able to see what groups exist, instead the user enters a PIN and if that PIN matches the PIN for an existing group, then the user becomes a member of that group.

Most of the answers I find are related to user authentication.

```
class Group(models.Model):  
    name = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    pin = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='members', blank=True)
```

Using the model above, I'd like any user who enters a pin that matches an existing pin to become a member of the corresponding group.

I'm also open to other ways to structure this, if you can offer a recommendation. I'd like to avoid inviting users to join the group via email or other ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a separate model to handle PINs. This is not strictly required, but I always have to allow expanded pin functionality. If you just want to keep your model, skip this step.

```
class Pin(models.Model): 
    pin = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    attached_group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
```

2. In your view, when the pin comes in, presumably via a POST, do this:

```
if request.method == POST: 
    group = Group.objects.get(pin=Pin.objects.get(request.POST.get("pin_from_form").pin))
group.members.add(request.user)
```

If you want to keep the same model:

```
group = Group.objects.get(pin=request.POST.get("pin_from_form"))
group.members.add(request.user)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm a newbie and appreciate the advise on creating a new model. Could you by chance point me to a reference on how to make that design decision?

Comment: I realize now that I have always used modelform, but struggled to figure out how to get a pin input. I needed a regular form to accept the PIN input. Apologies for my naive question.